# Multiple mod_login styles

Tags: login

I have a theme which is overriding the default Joomla login which works fine in the header (click for popup login box) but I would like the default Joomla login in the right hand sidebar on certain pages.
What do I need to do to be able to have both styles of login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your override a custom name, e.g. `popup.php`. Edit the module and in `Advanced` tab select the custom layout in `Layout` field.

Comment: Just trying to understand the steps with this one. In my theme folder I have the Mod_login folder which is where the theme developer has placed their overide. I added another folder taking the default joomla mod_login folder and copying it here and calling mod_standard_login. The files in the folder are all default. I can't see how to select this new module in the advance tab. Should I instead have a new php file in the same mod_login as an alternative to mod_login.php, e.g mod_standard_login.php?

Comment: Yes, all overrides must be placed in the same `mod_login` folder. If the template already has `default.php` override, create your own override with a different name, e.g. `sidebar.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Well in the mod_login folder there isn't a default.php but there is the mod_login.php. I duplicated the standard joomla mod_login.php file and copied it here and renamed as mod_standard_login.php. In the module in the admin system, going to advanced/ layouts I still only see 'from module' and default as the options. I wonder if I'm missing a step.

Comment: Sorry, in my testing, I deleted the default.php. Added back in now after I realised I broke the login module! Still, i have the alternative layout files in there too now but still don't see an alternative layout.

Comment: Renaming my default joomla file to just standard instead of having the _ in the filename fixed it! Thank you so much :)))))